# Distributing a proprietary app together with an ASLv2'ed derived work

Tags: java, licensing, apache-license, closed-source

My proprietary *Java* app includes a modified version of a 3rd party library distributed under *Apache Software License, version 2.0*. The 3rd party library doesn't come from the *Apache Software Foundation*, neither does it include any `NOTICE` file (mentioned in 4.(d) section of the License).

1. Do I need to distribute the modified source code? (I assume the answer is *no*, but just making sure.)
2. Would a free-form statement like "this product uses 3rd party software licensed under ASL 2.0, license available at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0" somewhere in the `THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt` file be sufficient?
3. Do I need to provide any information as per which exact ASLv2'ed software my product uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache has a [pretty good FAQ](https://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html) regarding their license. The relevant points:

1. No, you do not have to provide the source code.
2. Not quite. That statement almost covers the "proper attribution" requirement (but see #3), however you also are required to include a copy of the ASLv2 itself.
3. Bizarrely, I can't find anything on the Apache website to clarify this issue; it looks like the exact criteria for "proper attribution" appear to consist of preserving the NOTICE file and any notices in source files. Personally, I would be very surprised if "proper attribution" of a work did not include specifying what the work is and where it came from.